# Probability problem - Electrical circuit.

Tags: statistics

> A guided missile has five distinct sections through which a signal must pass 
>   if the missile is to operate properly. Each of the individual sections has 
>   two circuits through which the signal may pass, at least one of which must 
>   function if the signal is to traverse that section. The probability that any 
>   single circuit will fail is $0.02$.
>
> (a) calculate the probability that the signal passes through *any* section.
>
> (b) calculate the probability that a signal passes through *all* sections, 
>   thus allowing the missile to function.

Comment: The problem cannot be solved as stated. You need to know the probability that _both_ circuits in a section fail, and also something about the _joint_ probability of failure of circuits in different sections. Which book did the problem come from (and what is the name of the Chapter in which it is posed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are supposed to assume independence of all
circuits: first, because it is a common (and not always explicitly
stated) assumption in such problems; second, because this problem
can't be worked without some such assumption--or additional
information, as in the Comment from @DilipSarwate.

(a) Assuming the two circuits in a 'section' are independent, what is the probability one or the other of them works? Let $A_i$ be
the probability that the $i$th circuit is OK, for $i = 1,2$.
$$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2)
= P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1)P(A_2),$$
where the last equality is due to independence.
I hope you can take it from there.

It is sometimes said that two such circuits are connected 'in
parallel'. You might look to see if this terminology is used
in an example in your text.

(b) The 'sections' are connected 'in series'. That is, the
missile works only if all five sections work properly.
You have the probability $P(S_1) = P(S_2) = \cdots = P(S_5)$
from part (a). Use independence again to finish this part.

Note: In a practical setting, I'm not sure independence is
a reasonable assumption. Whatever vibration or cosmic ray happens by
chance to
zap one circuit might very well zap several of its neighbors.

I have left substantial chunks of this for you to do. Please
leave comments if you need more help.